# Change last column of a matrix

Tags: matrix, replacement

Given a (rectangular) matrix of integers, i.e.

```
RandomInteger[4, {10, 3}]
```

I want to apply the following rules only to the last column

```
rules = {0 -> 1000 ,1-> 11, 2-> 22, 3 -> 33, 4-> 44}
```

So for example if

```
mat = RandomInteger[4, {10, 3}]
```

is

```
{{2, 1, 0}, {3, 0, 1}, {4, 2, 1}, {2, 0, 3}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {3, 3, 2}, {0, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}
```

Then the code I use is

```
Flatten@{Most[##], Last[#] /. rules} & /@ mat

{{2, 1, 1000}, {3, 0, 11}, {4, 2, 11}, {2, 0, 33}, {1, 0, 1000}, {0, 0, 11}, {3, 3, 22}, {0, 2, 11}, {0, 1, 11}, {2, 1, 22}}
```

Any better code appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
mat = {{2, 1, 0}, {3, 0, 1}, {4, 2, 1}, {2, 0, 3}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1},
       {3, 3, 2}, {0, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}};
rules = {0 -> 1000 ,1-> 11, 2-> 22, 3 -> 33, 4-> 44};

mat[[All, -1]] = mat[[All, -1]] /. rules; mat
(* {{2, 1, 1000}, {3, 0, 11}, {4, 2, 11}, {2, 0, 33}, {1, 0, 1000}, 
    {0,  0, 11}, {3, 3, 22}, {0, 2, 11}, {0, 1, 11}, {2, 1, 22}} *)
```

or

```
MapAt[# /. rules &, mat, {{All, -1}}]
(* same output *)
```

or, changing the `rules` (as in @Pickett's answer)  -- not to another rule, but -- to a function,

```
ClearAll[f];
(f[x__, #] := {x, #2}) & @@@ rules;
f[x__] := {x};
f @@@ mat
(* same output *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
With[{m = Transpose[mat]}, Transpose[Append[Most[m], Last[m]/. rules]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

If the rule doesn't fit, change it:

```
rules = {a_, b_, #} :> {a, b, #2} & @@@ {0 -> 1000, 1 -> 11, 2 -> 22, 3 -> 33, 4 -> 44};
mat /. rules
```

> `{{4, 4, 1000}, {4, 1, 1000}, {1, 2, 33}, {3, 1, 1000}, {2, 0, 33},
>   {4,3, 33}, {2, 1, 11}, {2, 0, 44}, {3, 3, 22}, {1, 2, 22}}`

Answer (score 3):

```
mat[[All, -1]] = Transpose[mat][[-1]] /. rules; mat
```

> ```
> {{2, 1, 1000}, {3, 0, 11}, {4, 2, 11}, {2, 0, 33}, {1, 0, 1000}, {0, 0, 11}, {3, 3, 22},
>  {0, 2, 11}, {0, 1, 11}, {2, 1, 22}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of ways:

```
Cases[mat, {e__, l_} :> {e, l /. rules}]
```

or

```
ReplacePart[mat, {i_, 3} :> (mat[[i, 3]] /. rules)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = RandomInteger[4, {10, 3}];
rules = {0 -> 1000, 1 -> 11, 2 -> 22, 3 -> 33, 4 -> 44};

data /. {a__?NumberQ, b_} :> {a, b /. rules} // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`ReplaceAt`, introduced with `V 13.1`, is an ideal candidate for this task:

```
mat = {{2, 1, 0}, {3, 0, 1}, {4, 2, 1}, {2, 0, 3}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {3, 3, 2}, {0, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}};

rules = {0 -> 1000, 1 -> 11, 2 -> 22, 3 -> 33, 4 -> 44};

ReplaceAt[mat, rules, {All, -1}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Lookup`:**

```
amat = {{2, 1, 0}, {3, 0, 1}, {4, 2, 1}, {2, 0, 3}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
   1}, {3, 3, 2}, {0, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}

rules = {0 -> 1000, 1 -> 11, 2 -> 22, 3 -> 33, 4 -> 44}

(bmat = Join[
    Most /@ amat
    , Lookup[rules, {#}, {#}] & /@ Last /@ amat, 2]
  ) // MatrixForm
```

[image]